# c# - DataSet and DataGridView

Tags: c#

I have made a basic program to add values to a dataSet and display it to a dataGridView:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable("People");
        table1.Columns.Add("id");
        table1.Columns.Add("Name");
        table1.Columns.Add("Age");
        table1.Rows.Add(1, "Jack", 18);
        table1.Rows.Add(2, "Tim", 18);

        DataSet set = new DataSet("SetPeople");
        set.Tables.Add(table1);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = set;
        dataGridView1.Update();
    }
}
```

When I try it out nothing seems to happen. The dataGridView remains blank. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
   dataGridView1.DataSource = table1;
```

you don't need a Ds for just showing a data table in a Gridview

Answer (score 2):

Massimiliano Peluso is correct.  The GridView will reference a"Table", but more specifically, when using ADO.NET in a Disconnected fashion you will be filling the GridView with DataColumn objects that are part of a DataTable object.  You will also want to bind your dataTable to the GridView.

A bit of Detail:
ADO.Net's DataSet construct allows you to represent your database in a "table" like manner and allow those tables to share references.  All of this comes at the cost of additional memory overhead, but if this is not going to be a highly scalable applicaiton and you want to give the users the ability to edit rows without having to go to the database every time, DataSet is a good option.

If you are not using the featuers of DataSet (e.g. table relationships) you can save yourself a little overhead by just using DataTable objects and populating them.

To answer your questions:

A GridView expects to recieve a DataTable as a data source.  That table can contain several columns (which will fill the columns of the grid).  You can write the following code to specifically access your data table:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = set.Tables["table1"]; // or by index if you prefer as there are several overloads.
```

Additionally, I would bind the data by adding the following line of code after the one perscribed above:

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

The fact you are missing your DataBind() method call is part of your issue.

There is a very good example at C sharp corner site: [Example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/abhikumarvatsa/using-a-disconnected-datatable-to-display-records-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/)

Answer (score 0):

> You could also do this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = set;
dataGridView1.DataMember = set.Tables["People"].TableName;
dataGridView1.Update();
```